Medusa Subscriber Not Logging Product Updates
I'm having trouble with a Medusa subscriber that's supposed to log product update events. The subscriber is being triggered, but the log message is not appearing.
import {
    ProductService,
    Logger,
    type SubscriberConfig,
    type SubscriberArgs,
  } from "@medusajs/medusa";
  
  export default async function productHandler({
    data,
    eventName,
    container,
    pluginOptions,
  }: SubscriberArgs<Record<string, any>>) {
    const productService: ProductService = container.resolve("productService");
    const logger: Logger = container.resolve<Logger>("logger");
  
    const { id } = data;
  
    try {
      const product = await productService.retrieve(id);
  
      if (eventName === ProductService.Events.CREATED) {
        const message = `Product created: ${JSON.stringify(product, null, 2)}`; 
        logger.debug(message);
      } else if (eventName === ProductService.Events.UPDATED) {
        const message = `Product updated: ${JSON.stringify(product, null, 2)}`;
        logger.debug(message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error("Error retrieving product:", error);
    }
  }
  
  export const config: SubscriberConfig = {
    event: [ProductService.Events.CREATED, ProductService.Events.UPDATED],
    context: {
      subscriberId: "product-handler",
    },
  };

I tried to create a custom Medusa subscriber to log product update events, but the log messages are not appearing. I expected the subscriber to be triggered and the log messages to be output to the console, but the logs are missing.
